# Make a MySQL Workbench connection read only

Tags: mysql-workbench

I do not have access to the server. I can only set options for MySQL Workbench itself.

The problem I have is that for a certain website, if I update a row by accident, it crashes the database due to some badly set up cluster or something.

I want a connection to be treated like I only have read access so that there is no "apply" button when editing a table for in-case I forget.

So, is it possible to set some option to force read only mode on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. It would require to modify quite a part of the UI for a very questionable feature. If have no rights to change data you will get an error anyway when trying to apply changes.

Comment: Yeah. It definitely is questionable but I have no choice. Sometimes you have to deal with really bad clients. And, as stated above, they didn't set up the user accounts properly. But you've answered the questions if it is indeed not possible. Thanks